# dotnet ef database update - Database already exists

Tags: .net, .net-core, gitlab-ci-runner

I am creating a .gitlab-ci.yml deployment in Gitlab and want dotnet to update the database to the latest migrations.

Running this command from the server works. But running this command (in our yml) using the Gitlab Runner returns an error:

```
  - set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
  - dotnet ef database update --project %PROJECT_NAME%\\%PROJECT_NAME%.csproj --configuration Release --verbose
```

> Database 'OurDB' already exists. Choose a different database name.

Any ideas what we are doing wrong? Instead of simply updating the database it seems like it trying to create it.

Have examined these documentations without luck:
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/commands/cli-commands
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

We are using Dotnet Core 2.2

Answer (score 0):

As strange as it seems. this error message was caused by a permission missing for the NT ATHORITY/SYSTEM user to create databases in mssql.